# Is the support to MobileElement no more available starting from the latest versions of Appium java-client I.e 8.5.1?

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, ui-automation

I just wanted to as a quick question to all the people here
Is the support to MobileElement no more available starting from the latest versions of Appium java-client I.e 8.5.1 ??
I ask this because I have added the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.appium</groupId>
<artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
<version>8.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

To my maven project POM.xml and there is an error at the import statement “import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;” which says “The import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement cannot be
resolved”
Also
There is an news @ https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/v7-to-v8-migration-guide.md#mobileelement. Stating that “ • DefaultGenericMobileElement class has been removed completely together with its descendants (MobileElement, IOSElement, AndroidElement etc.). Use WebElement instead.”
Should this mean that MobileElement is no useful and permitted with the latest versions of Appium java-client I.e 8.5.1  and all the capabilities I.e mobile specific actions such as setValue(), swipe(), pinch(), and zoom(). Are moved to/will be available with WebElement from Appium java-client I.e 8.5.1 . I am little confused here. Any better early clarity from anyone of you will be much appreciated. Please do comment if you need any additional information related to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use AppiumBy specific class for appium to access your elements:

```
        driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("open menu")).click();
```

, i strongly recommend this **playlist**:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQFRgOI8-3o&list=PL9ok7C7Yn9A99LiTcemmKmupBdNB38bbo&pp=iAQB

what you are looking for is in video 4:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hD9Bgb1LSy0&t=137s&ab_channel=TestingMiniBytes

**upvote** if this helps